# Compute a double sum in R

Tags: r, statistics, sum

I have to compute a test statistic with a double sum.

I solved it like this:

```
T<-numeric(1)
for(j in 1:n){
   for(k in 1:n){
 T = T + ((1/n)*(exp(-(1/2)*((Y[j]-Y[k])^2))))}
 T = T - ((sqrt(2))*(exp(-(1/4)*((Y[j])^2))))}
 T = T + (n*(3^(-(1/2))))
```

Is there an easier way to compute the test statistic?

Comment: `Y` can't be *`a given random value`* as you indexing it, it has to be a vector

Comment: Sorry,
Y is a given random vector and n is the sampling scope, for example n=100.

Comment: What do you mean by "easier"? More elegant? More efficient? If there exists a package/function for this task? You could take a look at `?outer` that operates on all combinations of two vectors (here "Y[1:n]" and "Y[1:n]") but `outer` can run into memory problems since it has to return a "length(x) * length(y)" matrix to work with.

Comment: Think about accepting an answer if any of the solutions provided you with what you need. This way, the question gets tagged as having an answer (useful for others), and further contributions are encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

It's more useful to create the indexes in advance and then just sum over an array rather than computing new indices over two nested loops

```
indexes = expand.grid(1:n,1:n)
T = 1/n*sum(exp(-1/2*(Y[indexes[,1]]-Y[indexes[,2]])))
T = T-(sqrt(2))*sum(exp(-1/4*(Y[1:n])))
T = T+n/sqrt(3)
```

Edit: For large n, this is impractical, as an `n` of 1,000,000 would make a 3.7 TB data frame with `expand.grid`.  You can always use the for loops, even if they are slow, but I would recommend using C++ if you need to have absurdly large N, because that is 1 trillion loops, which will take a very long time to compute.

Comment: This does not give the same answer as the OP, typo and nested loop logic error? The exponent in (Y-Y)^2 and Y are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
n=100;
Y=runif(100);
T=0;

Ydiff=outer(Y,Y,"-")^2;
Y_1=exp(-0.5*Ydiff);
Y_2=sqrt(2)*exp(-0.25*Y^2);

T=sum(rowMeans(Y_1)-Y_2) + (n*(3^(-(1/2))))
```

Comparison of methods given so far give:

```
T=0;
n=100;
set.seed(100)
Y=runif(100);
for(j in 1:n){
  for(k in 1:n){
    T = T + ((1/n)*(exp(-(1/2)*((Y[j]-Y[k])^2))));
  }
  T = T - ((sqrt(2))*(exp(-(1/4)*((Y[j])^2))));
}
T = T + (n*(3^(-(1/2))));
print(T)
#21.18983

T=0;
Ydiff=outer(Y,Y,"-")^2;
Y_1=exp(-0.5*Ydiff);
Y_2=sqrt(2)*exp(-0.25*Y^2);
T=sum(rowMeans(Y_1)-Y_2) + (n*(3^(-(1/2))));
print(T)
# 21.18983

T=0;
indexes = expand.grid(1:n,1:n);
T = 1/n*sum(exp(-1/2)*((Y[indexes[,1]]-Y[indexes[,2]])));
T = T-(sqrt(2))*sum(exp(-1/4*(Y[1:n])));
T = T+n/sqrt(3);
print(T)
# -66.71403
```